# Angular JS - Nested http calls to SharePoint Lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a requirement on retrieving data from multiple SharePoint lists and creating a joined model to be displayed in the view. We have two lists Employee and Department. Employee list would have field as "Department" which needs to be joined with Department List's Title Field

Below is the controller along with used services, but it is not working as expected.

Employee List data

[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "1",
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Salary": 1000,
        "Department": "1",
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "2",
        "Name": "DEF",
        "Salary": 600,
        "Department": "2",
        "ID": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Title": "3",
        "Name": "GHI",
        "Salary": 500,
        "Department": "3",
        "ID": 3
    }
]

Department List data

[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Title": "1",
        "Name": "DOC",
        "Location": "DIJ",
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Title": "2",
        "Name": "DYU",
        "Location": "RTY",
        "ID": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Title": "3",
        "Name": "UCV",
        "Location": "TYU",
        "ID": 3
    }
]

I am getting some [ngRepeat:dupes] error.

```
(function () {
    angular.module("app")
            .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'employeeService', 'departmentService', function ($scope, employeeService, departmentService) {
                var employeevm = {};
                var employeesvm = [];
                employeeService.getAll()
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.employees = response.d.results;
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.employees.length; i++) {
                        employeevm.Id = $scope.employees[i].Title;
                        employeevm.Name = $scope.employees[i].Name;
                        employeevm.Salary = $scope.employees[i].Salary;
                        departmentService.getItem($scope.employees[i].Department)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.department = response.d.results;
                            employeevm.DepartmentName = $scope.department[0].Name;
                            employeevm.Location = $scope.department[0].Location;

                            employeesvm.push(employeevm);
                        })
                    }
                    $scope.employeesvm = employeesvm;
                })
            }]);
})();
```

EmployeeService.js

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module("app")
    .factory("employeeService", ["baseSpServices", function (baseService) {
        var listEndPoint = '/_api/web/lists';
        var getAll = function () {
            var query = listEndPoint + "/GetByTitle('Employee')/Items?$select=ID,Title,Name,Salary,Department";
            return baseService.getRequest(query);
        };
        return {
            getAll: getAll,
        };
    }]);
})();
```

departmentService.js

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module("app")
    .factory("departmentService", ["baseSpServices", function (baseService) {
        var listEndPoint = '/_api/web/lists';
        var getItem = function (id) {
            var query = listEndPoint + "/GetByTitle('Department')/Items?$select=ID,Title,Name,Location&$filter=Title eq " + id;
            return baseService.getRequest(query);
        }
        return {
            getItem: getItem
        };
    }]);
})();
```

baseSPService.js

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    angular.module("app")
        .factory("baseSpServices", ["$http", "$q", "spContext", function ($http, $q, spContext) {
            var baseUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
            var getRequest = function (query) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: baseUrl + query,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result, status) {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            var postRequest = function (data, url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: baseUrl + url,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result, status) {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            var updateRequest = function (data, url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: baseUrl + url,
                    method: "PATCH",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
                        "If-Match": "*"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result, status) {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            var deleteRequest = function (url) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    url: baseUrl + url,
                    method: "DELETE",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
                        "IF-MATCH": "*"
                    }
                })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        deferred.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result, status) {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
            return {
                getRequest: getRequest,
                postRequest: postRequest,
                updateRequest: updateRequest,
                deleteRequest: deleteRequest
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my controller as below. I am pretty sure the issue was with handling the promises. Any help on handling error and other performance refinements is very much helpful

```
(function () {
    angular.module("app")
            .controller('homeCtrl', ['$filter', '$scope', '$q', 'employeeService', 'departmentService', function ($filter, $scope, $q, employeeService, departmentService) {

                var departments = [];
                var employeesvm = [];

                employeeService.getAll()
                    .then(function (employees) {
                        var promises = [];
                        $scope.employees = employees.d.results;
                        angular.forEach($scope.employees, function (employee) {
                            promises.push(departmentService.getItem(employee.Department));
                        })
                        $q.all(promises).then(function (responses) {
                            departments = [];
                            angular.forEach(responses, function (response) {
                                departments.push(response.d.results[0]);
                            })

                            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.employees.length; i++) {
                                var employeevm = {};

                                employeevm.Id = $scope.employees[i].Title;
                                employeevm.Name = $scope.employees[i].Name;
                                employeevm.Salary = $scope.employees[i].Salary;
                                var department = $filter('filter')(departments, { Title: $scope.employees[i].Department });
                                employeevm.DepartmentName = department[0].Name;
                                employeevm.Location = department[0].Location;

                                employeesvm.push(employeevm);
                            }

                            $scope.employeesvm = employeesvm;
                        })
                    })


            }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much information about what exactly is not working as expected.

Just by viewing your code it looks like your nested `then` could be the problem. You assign `response.d.results` to `$scope.department`, then read values from `$scope.department` and assign them to properties of `employeevm`. The problem is that the nested `then` runs multiple times, so the value assigned to `$scope.department` is going to change over time.

I'd suggest not assigning anything to `$scope.department` at all but instead just use the response directly, as follows:

```
.then(function (response) {
    employeevm.DepartmentName = response.d.results[0].Name;
    employeevm.Location = response.d.results[0].Location;
    employeesvm.push(employeevm);
}
```

If that's not the problem please provide more information on what's not working.

Comment: No the solution didn't work. I have updated the input and result. I am expecting the joined result to be displayed in the view. Thanks

Comment: Did you intend to assign title to the Id field? I suspect title isn't unique. Try assigning Id to employeevm.id instead. You'll need a new title property as well if you want that information too.

Comment: Please also provide your `ng-repeat` line. If you're repeating over a field that has duplicates, such as title, my previous comment still won't fix this. You'll need to repeat over a unique property. You could use a filter to achieve this, or `track by $index` inside your ng-repeat.

Comment: I guess the issue is with the promises. I have modified my controller which resolved the issue.